# Should duplicates be made from low quality questions?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

I am trying to improve on my question and am having trouble. The linked duplicate I believe is not helping.  My question was mark as a duplicate to a poor received question also does not answer may question. How can I separate my question from that one? Any ideas?

I asked: [Where did the name Jesus originate from?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/69648/where-did-the-name-jesus-originate-from) which is related but not the same as the question below.

[Is Jesus the real name of Jesus or is it some kind of translation?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/45849/is-jesus-the-real-name-of-jesus-or-is-it-some-kind-of-translation)

I need the question to be well-received. If it cannot be made better I will be stuck in SE question purgatory for 6 months.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On most SE sites, the standard for duplicates is whether the answers are valid: your question is a duplicate of the older question because it's answer pretty well explains where the name comes from.  The fact that it's downvoted and closed as a duplicate itself doesn't matter, it still has an answer to your question.